# A number when divided by 899 gives a remainder 63. The remainder when this number is divided by 29 is?

Tags: modular-arithmetic, arithmetic

Am I supposed  to try division  algorithm  . I don't  know  what  to do at all . Plz help

Comment: $899=900-1=(30+1)(30-1)=31\cdot 29$. Something of the kind must be true for the question to have any definite answer. For $a$ and $b$ co-prime any pair of residues is possible (see Chinese Remainder Theorem)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the number be $a$. By assumption, we have $$a=899q+63.$$

Noting that $899=29\times 31$, we have
$$a=29(31q)+63=29(31q)+2\times 29+5$$
so,
$$a=29(31q+2)+5$$
thus the remainder is $5$.

Answer (score 2):

Here the key is that $29 | 899$ so we can write:

$$n=899k+63$$

Where $n$ is our number.

$$n=29(31k)+63$$
$$n=29(31k)+29\times 2 +5$$
$$n=29(31k+2)+5$$
$$n\equiv 5 \pmod{29}$$

:)

Comment: kk thanks btw could you explain what mod is ? is it modulus function ?? please answer